# 4 digit numbers divisible by 11

Tags: permutations

**Four digit numbers are formed using the
digits 1,2,3,4 (repetition is allowed). The
number of such four digit numbers divisible
by 11 is-**
(1) 22 (2) 36 (3) 44 (4) 52

I know for a number to be divisible by 11 the sum of digits at even places must be equal to the sum of those at odd places. But how do I use this to get the answer?

Comment: I would break into cases based on what the sum of the even places is.  The odd places must have the same sum.  If the sum is $2$, then that can only be accomplished using two ones, giving the four digit number $1111$.  If the sum of the even places is $3$, then that can be accomplished either as a $1$ followed by a $2$, or vice versa, for two options on how to fill the even slots.  Similarly we will have the same two options for how to fill the odd slots.  Applying [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) we get four possibilities here, 1122, 1221, 2112, 2211.  Continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $abcd$ be the number.

If $a=b$ then $c=d$.  There are $4*4=16$ ways that can occur. (Four options for $a$ and four options for $b$).

If $a=b\pm 1$ then $c=d \mp1$.  And there are $2*3*3=18$ ways this can occur. (Two choices whether $a > b$ or $b > a$ and three choices from $1,2,3,4$ that are one apart.

If $a = b\pm 2$ then $c = d\mp 2$ and there $ 2*2*2 = 8$ ways.

And if $a = b\pm 4$ then either $a = 1;b=4;c=4;d=1$ or $a=4;b=1;c=1;d=4$.  $2$ ways.

So $16 + 18 + 8 + 2 = 44$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, consider permutations of numbers made of one, two, three and four digits.

There is one number made of single number $1$, which is $1111$. Total number is:
$$1\cdot {4\choose 1}=4.$$

There are four numbers made of two digits $1$ and $2$, which are $1122,1221,2112,2211$. Total number is:
$$4\cdot {4\choose 2}=24.$$

There are four numbers made of three digits $1,2,3$, which are $1232,2123,2321,3212$. And there are two possible cases: $1,2,3$ and $2,3,4$. Total number is:
$$4\cdot 2=8.$$

There are eight numbers made of four digits $1,2,3,4$, which are $1234,1342,2134,2431,3241,3421,4213,4312$. Total number is:
$$8\cdot 1=8.$$

In conclusion, the grand total is:
$$4+24+8+8=44.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $[abcd]$ be the number. Then $[abcd] \equiv [ab]+[cd] \pmod{99}$ which implies $[abcd] \equiv [ab]+[cd] \pmod{11}$. Because $a,b,c,d \in \{1,2,3,4\}$,
$[abcd] \equiv [(a+c)(b+d)] \pmod{11}$. Hence $[abcd]$ is a multiple of $11$ if and only if $a+c=b+d$.

\begin{array}{|r|r|r|}
\text{sum} &\text{ac and bd events} & \text{counts} \\
\hline
  2 &                   11 & 1\\
  3 &             12, \ 21 & 4\\
  4 &       13, \ 22, \ 31 & 9 \\
  5 & 14, \ 23, \ 32, \ 41 & 16\\
  6 &       24, \ 33, \ 42 & 9\\
  7 &              34, \ 43 & 4\\
  8 &                    44 & 1 \\
\hline
\text{total} && 44
\end{array}